# looking for an imagemagick nodejs npm?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, node-imagemagick

I have bene using [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) for a few days now and have come to realize that it has bugs.

There are about 100 forks of it, some of which fix some of the issues i have come across, but it is hard to figure out which fork i should use.

Comment: for now, switched to: https://github.com/dogichow/node-imagemagick

Comment: Check out [Wizardry](http://diy.github.com/wizardry/). It might work somewhat better...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I chose to use **gm** node module on one of my project. It works pretty well.

See : http://aheckmann.github.com/gm/

It's basically a wrapper around **imageMagick** or **graphicsmagick** binaries.

Here is  a simple example :

```js
var gm = require('gm');
gm('/path/to/image.jpg')
.resize(353, 257)
.autoOrient()
.write(writeStream, function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log(' hooray! ');
});
```

Comment: This is not working at all for me.getting { [Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - -resize
] code: 4, signal: null } .:/

Comment: new link is : https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm

Answer (score 33):

I once was in your position and after getting really frustrated with modules that had bugs or weird APIs I started using imagemagic directly by spawning a child process. Node.js is pretty good at this so it's actually not that hard.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var args = ['-ping', 'tree.gif' ];
var composite = spawn('identify', args);
```

It's also great because you can just use the imagemagic documentation.